# Closure compiler typing: Refer to function (factory method)

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Suppose I have a class with a factory method:

```
export class Foo {
    constructor(options) {
        this.a = options.a;
        this.b = options.b;
    }

    /**
     * @param {{
     *   a: number,
     *   b: number
     * }} options
     * @return {!Foo}
     */
    static create(options) {
        return new Foo(options);
    }
}
```

I want to dependency inject `Foo`'s factory method in another class, like:

```
/**
 * @param {{
 *   createFoo: !function(!Object): !Foo
 * }} options
 */
```

The problem: Closure Compiler says this does not match the formal parameter.

```
found   : {
  createFoo: function ({a: number, b: number): Foo, 
}

required: {
  createFoo: function (Object): Foo, 
}
```

Obviously I can rewrite the type signature and hard code in the record, but I really want to refer to `Foo.create` so there's no need to update the entire codebase every time I add a new param to the options object.

How can I do this for CC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general problem is that you are requiring a function that is more accepting than the Foo.create method.  Nick Santos wrote a good explanation of this:

http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/06/subtyping-functions-without-poking-your.html

Using a loose function type "Function" or "!Function" will work as you would hope.

I used this definition to verify:

```
/** @param {{createFoo: !Function}} options */
function f(options) {}

f({createFoo: Foo.create});
```

[CC debugger sample](http://closure-compiler-debugger.appspot.com/#input0%3Dclass%2520Foo%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520constructor(options)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.a%2520%253D%2520options.a%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.b%2520%253D%2520options.b%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F**%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257B%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%2520%2520%2520a%253A%2520number%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%2520%2520%2520b%253A%2520number%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%2520%257D%257D%2520options%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%2520%2540return%2520%257B!Foo%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%252F%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520static%2520create(options)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520new%2520Foo(options)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257B%257BcreateFoo%253A%2520!Function%257D%257D%2520options%250A%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520f(options)%2520%257B%250A%257D%250A%250Af(%257BcreateFoo%253A%2520Foo.create%257D)%253B%250A%250A%26input1%26conformanceConfig%26externs%26refasterjs-template%26includeDefaultExterns%3D1%26CHECK_SYMBOLS%3D1%26CHECK_TYPES%3D1%26LANG_IN_IS_ES6%3D1%26MISSING_PROPERTIES%3D1%26PRESERVE_TYPE_ANNOTATIONS%3D1%26PRETTY_PRINT%3D1%26TRANSPILE%3D1)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to write the type once in a typedef, and then refer to it in both places. (I haven't tried this but I think it should work)

```
/** @typedef {function({a: number, b:number}): Foo} */
var FooCreator;

export class Foo {
    ...

    /**
     * @type {FooCreator}
     */
    static create(options) {
        return new Foo(options);
    }
}

/**
 * @param {{
 *   createFoo: FooCreator
 * }} options
 */
```